# vmware equivalent to parallels tranporter agent

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

Is there a vmware tool to clone machines like it can be done with paralells tranporter agent for parallels. I want to run the vm on VMware ESXi 4.1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course there is, a variety based on what OS/API you want to use - did you do any research on this of your own?

http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/ under 'http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/', it's like 10 keystrokes and 1 click  away.

Comment: OK, it can be done with VMware Converter